# Do I need formal consent to use a Google Maps images in printed materials

Tags: google-my-maps

I was directed to this site to ask permission to use a portion of a Google map in a printed mailing piece by a Google representative. I am a public relations coordinator for a non-profit community mental health facility. Somewhat confused why I would post this question here as I am looking for formal consent to use Google Map imagery. What rules regulate taking a snap shot or capture of the map for printed use on a card, which may be distributed to people at resource events or by mail etc.?

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a strange place to send you for a question like that!

However - you can find Google's policies for non-profit use here:    https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html

I'm not brave enough to interpret them for you, but hopefully you can find the information you need there.

fyi, in case you come to the conclusion that you cannot use pictures from Google Maps, you might also investigate [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org).    Again, I'm not brave enough to interpret their policies for you.